# Add a subview or new view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, ios6, subview

I've been working a several projects and I am always at a loss on when it is best to either add a subview or use a push a new view controller.

To be more specific, lets say I have a main user interface (view controller) which has a number of items such as image views, text views and picker views. Instead of showing all these things in one long scroll view, I've been pushing separate view controllers and storing their selection, text, etc, values in a singleton to be incorporated into the main view on pop.

So my question is when is it better programming practice to use subviews instead of view controllers and why?

Comment: Its depend on how you make user experience from your application.. If you collect more data in a same view controller, you can separate pickerviews and datepickers to another view controller to get the data like apple do in some native apps. and you dont need singleton class to get the data from pushed view controller. You can simply use delegate calls using protocols..try it will be useful for u..

Comment: Thanks R.A. you've given me some food for thought here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to answer this in general, but here are the considerations I use:

1. Minimize depth of user interface (don't force lots of levels);
2. Keep similar things together and different things separate (organize by meaningful groups);
3. Keep the user interface simple (not too much on one page).

Obviously, these considerations conflict with each other -- it's an optimization problem. Use your judgement and test with real users.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess it boils down to designing as logical and sensibly flowing interface for the task at hand.